# Convert callback to co-routine with constraint on main thread for initial call

Tags: kotlin, callback, kotlin-coroutines, dispatcher

I would like to convert a callback to co-routine, and the SDK states that the API call needs to be made on the main thread. The solution works, but I am not confident that it is correct in principle.

It looks like this roughly:

```
   override suspend fun registerUser(email: String): ResultHandler<Profile, Exception> {

        return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->

            val observer =
                object : Observer<RegisterResponse<Profile?>> {
               fun onNext(t: Profile) {
                 continuation.resume(Success(t))
           }

     CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
         userManager.register(email, observer)
       }
}
}
```

It seems to me that the SDK wants to invoke the observer callback on the Main thread, but my process is triggered in a view model scope on the IO thread (to avoid blocking main). So the observer I guess is in practice running on the IO thread.

Thoughts on how to approach this?

Comment: "looks like this roughly" You didn't post valid code or syntax, so how can we tell what's wrong with your real code? Also, the indention is all over the place so I can't tell if that other coroutine you're launching is happening inside the `suspendCancellableCoroutine` lambda, or inside the `observer` anonymous class, or completely outside all of it.

Comment: The fact that this callback's function is called "onNext" instead of "onSuccess" or "onFinished" or something like that suggests that it is called multiple times and is therefore not suited to a suspend function at all. It might be more appropriate to convert it into a coroutine Flow.

Comment: @Tenfour04 The code is working. The question is about working across threads: main thread vs Io thread.

Comment: @Tenfour04 For the onNext- it so happens that the SDK uses this structure, but only a single event is actually needed/used. We started with a flow, but realized that the actual process is single shot. As far as I am aware, a single in RxJava still has a onNext?

Comment: Do you register and unregister these observers, or does the API only ever fire the callback once and then drop the observer reference? If so, can you cancel the observer prematurely? The reason I ask is to be sure I can recommend code that doesn’t cause memory leaks. If it does fire it multiple times until you unregister, then I would just make this a flow and then call `first()` on the flow because that would be less convoluted to implement.

Comment: There is no registration/unregistration from our side. They recommend to create a disposable, hold onto it, and dispose it when needed.In short, I think the SDK drops the observer reference.  I am running leak canary, so should pick up issues about memory leaks

Comment: If you are using RxJava, you can simply do [`.await()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-rx3/kotlinx.coroutines.rx3/await.html).

Comment: @GeorgeLeung I think I tried that at first, but await is only available on an observable, not an observer.

Comment: To what object are you passing your `observer` to? You have redacted that from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get this out of the way, if this library provided you an ObservableSource reference instead of making you pass it an Observer, you could use [`awaitFirst()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-rx3/kotlinx.coroutines.rx3/await-first.html) on it, which would of course be simpler than implementing this yourself.

---

Avoid doing this: `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch` which is essentially no different than using `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)`. It creates an unbound (never cancelled) scope, which is a common source of memory leaks. If the coroutine that is calling this suspend function is cancelled, the other coroutine you have launched will not be notified and cancelled, since it is not a child.

Secondly, the other coroutine does not wait for it--the events of the inner coroutine can come some time in the future.

To ensure you register your API on the main thread, use a `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` call around this whole function. Then, the `suspendCancellableCoroutine` lambda block will run on the main thread, so you'll be calling the API registration function on the main thread.

Some other points about implementing this:

- Observer has an `onSubscribe` function that hands you a Disposable that you can use to cancel early. You need to do this to support cancellation.
- Calling `continuation.resume()` more than once will crash your coroutine, so you need some safeguards just in case the API surprises you and emits more than one item.
- I added another safeguard for the possible case of the subscription ending without emitting anything.
- In `onError`, I also check `continuation.isActive` to avoid a multiple-resume crash in the possible case of a single item being emitted followed by an error occurring before the subscription ends.

Since the Kotlin coroutines library is open source, you can see how they implemented `Observable.await` [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/ca14606d1f60780663dbcf54b58d2bb2b5e10f7d/reactive/kotlinx-coroutines-rx3/src/RxAwait.kt#L220) for an example of how to do this kind of thing properly.

The solution should look something like:

```
override suspend fun registerUser(email: String): ResultHandler<Profile, Exception> = withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
        val observer = object : Observer<RegisterResponse<Profile?>> {
            lateinit var subscription: Disposable
            var seenValue = false

            override fun onSubscribe(disposable: Disposable) {
                subscription = disposable
                continuation.invokeOnCancellation { subscription.dispose() }
            }

            override fun onNext(t: Profile) {
                 if (!seenValue) {
                     seenValue = true
                     continuation.resume(Success(t))
                     subscription.dispose()
                 }
            }

            override fun onComplete() {
                if (continuation.isActive && !seenValue) {
                    continuation.resume(Error(NoSuchElementException("Observer completed without emitting any value.")))
                }
            }

            override fun onError(throwable: Throwable) {
                if (continuation.isActive) continuation.resume(Error(throwable))
            }
        }
        userManager.register(email, observer)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Great idea about seenValue and isActive.  I need to wrap my head around why withContext(Dispatchers.Main) around the whole call does not block the main thread. I tried to defer the Dispatchers.Main usage until the point of calling the API.

Comment: There is nothing blocking anywhere in this code. Creating an observer is trivial. Passing an observer to another class is trivial. These functions are being called on the main thread, but they aren’t blocking functions. The whole `suspendCancellableCoroutine` is called on the main thread, and then the function as a whole suspends (relinquishes the main thread) until resume is called on the continuation.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that is what I was trying to work out yesterday: how we communicate to the system the difference between waiting for a job in a blocking way, and simply giving access to a thread when it is needed. The suspendCancellableCoroutine would give me the impression that the system would be waiting until it gets a result.

Comment: The only ways I know of that tell the coroutines system to wait without blocking (which relinquishes the thread back to its dispatcher) is calling `suspendCoroutine`, `suspendCancellableCoroutine` or `delay()`. These work with it at a low level to tell it to give up the thread and suspend until `continuation.resume()` is called (except with `delay`). Almost all other suspend functions use one of these, at least indirectly by calling other suspend functions that use them.